# Connect Power BI to SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, powerbi

I have a database in the SQL Azure Service (not in a VM).  I can connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio but I'm not able to connect using Power BI Desktop edition.  The error is very generic[image]

"Unable to connect".  I have tried to connect using both an AD and a SQL user.  Is there a way to debug or troubleshoot a Power BI connection ?  I do think Power BI is finding the server because if I put in a nonexistent server I get a message that the server can't be found.  I'm wondering if this has something to do with the account I log into Power BI with although I have tried logging in to Power BI with the Azure admin account and I get the same failure message as in the screen capture image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**step 1**
 clean the stored credentials in the power bi
-file>option and setting> data source setting> find your azure server and delete/clear permission

- and then try to login using database login method in powerbi and **provide the azure server name and  optional database**
- note: azure sql server name should be like this : xxx.database.windows.net

make sure, if you are able to log in on the server using ssms then use powerbi on the same machine

For detailed steps
http://www.powerbipanda.com/2017/04/error-connecting-power-bi-to-azure-sql.html